# Turning off Ambient Mode in MI phones

Tags: android, android-intent, settings, ambient

After recent update MI note 5 pro shows ambient mode while charging.
I want to disable ambient mode but did not got setting.
If any one know how to disable mode while charging please let me know.

Comment: I think you should probably ask at https://android.stackexchange.com/ or clarify your question.

Comment: sure. I want to disable Ambient Mode in Android phone. 
because in ambient mode finger print cant work and phone can be unlocked directly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is how I did it for my Mi A1:

You have to go to the Google app > More > Settings > Google assistant > Assistant tab > scroll down to Assistant devices > select your device (mine was phone) > find Ambient mode > deactivate.

(there was no settings gear in on the screen for me)

Comment: Here is steps for [MIUI 12/Redmi K20Pro phone](http://techieroop.com/how-to-turn-on-off-ambient-mode-during-charging-in-miui-12-redmi-phones/)

Answer (score 0):

MIUI 11.0.3:

- Go to Google Assistant (Settings -> Aditional Settings -> Button Shortcuts -> Launch Google Assistant -> pick an option and finally lauch GA. Surely there's an easier way to do this)
- Click bottom left icon
- Click on profile icon, top right
- Switch to the 'Assistant' tab
- Scroll down to 'Assistant devices' and select your phone
- Under 'Personalisation' you will find 'Ambient Mode'

Answer (score 0):

Open "google" app --> more --> settings --> google assistent --> assistant tab.
In the assistant device section select your device. Then find ambient mode and turn off.

Answer (score -1):

While on the lock screen you will find a gear symbol at bottom right side click there then there you will find the toggle button to turn off the ambient display feature.